# Can't un-archive site after upgrading to Wordpress 3.8

Tags: multisite

After upgrading to Wordpress 3.8, both of my network sites were archived.

I could un-archive one, but the other has no option to un-archive in the Sites list:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- go to php my admin
- click on database name
- go to wp_blogs
- see the column named archive
- You will see the value as 1 in this column. change it to 0 and save.
- everything will become fine.